# How to implement bloc with rxdart in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bloc, rxdart

[Github repo flutter bloc](https://github.com/iampawan/FlutterLoginPageBloc)

This above github repo explains bloc pattern in flutter with the help of rxdart. For the two Input fields it works properly.

I try to implement for the single input. I am unable to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in blow Code:

```
 Stream<bool> get submitCheck =>
  Observable.combineLatest2(email, password, (e, p) => true);
```

this code will wait until both email and password values to change. and after that, it will emit a true value. if you have single value I think you should change code to something like this:

```
Stream<bool> get submitCheck => email.map((item){ 
  //check your validation
  return item !=null;
});
```

create your validation and button will be active if the incoming value is true .
and if you want to use bloc pattern I will suggest you check [this package](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/).